Movie about people lost up a mountain in the snow
I've been trying to remember the name of a (probably) 90s English language American or Canadian movie.
In it, some people (I think a family) go mountain climbing. They eventually split up -- possibly the son goes with the father while the daughter goes with the mother. They get stranded in the snow/blizzard, and I remember the father and son get gangrene.
Trying to find it myself results only in finding Struggle to Survive aka Snowbound: The Jim and Jennifer Stolpa Story, which it is not.

I believe this movie is Anything to Survive. I remember that Matt Leblanc was in it, so searched him to find the name of the movie.
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anything_to_Survive

The plot concerns the family going to extreme lengths to survive after they get stranded on an island in a storm and lose their boat. Billy builds a raft and they attempt to sail to safety but they don't get far. Eddie and Billie head off to seek help while the two daughters try to keep warm under the remains of their boat's sail. Eddie and Billy find their way to a cabin on the mainland but can't raise help. On day 23 they are able to return to the island and find that the girls are alive. Eddie and Wendy have frostbitten feet but all in the family survive and they are able to return to Ketchikan

